# How to filter the data on array and remove some data in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

```
const data = [
  {
    status: "ESCALTED",
    name: "A1",
    ack: true
  },
  {
    status: "ESCALTED",
    name: "A2",
    ack: true
  },
  {
    status: "CLOSED",
    name: "A3",
    ack: true
  },
  {
    status: "NEW",
    name: "A4",
    ack: false
  },
  {
    status: "NEW",
    name: "A5",
    ack: true
  }
];
```

What I'm trying to filter all the objects with `ack` property equal to `true` and if the `status` is `CLOSED` or `ESCALATED`, it should be removed.

The output should be like this:

```
  [{
    status: "NEW",
    name: "A5",
    ack: true
  }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get the required output by filtering your array.

Try the below code:

```js
const data = [
  {
    status: "ESCALTED",
    name: "A1",
    ack: true
  },
  {
    status: "ESCALTED",
    name: "A2",
    ack: true
  },
  {
    status: "CLOSED",
    name: "A3",
    ack: true
  },
  {
    status: "NEW",
    name: "A4",
    ack: false
  },
  {
    status: "NEW",
    name: "A5",
    ack: true
  }
];

const output = data.filter(obj => obj.ack && obj.status != 'CLOSED' && obj.status != 'ESCALTED')

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter it like,

**For Angular and Angularjs with typescript,**

```
data = data.filter(ele => ele.ack === true && status !== 'CLOSED' && status !== 'ESCALATED'));
```

**Angularjs with javascript,**

Add `$filter` dependency into your controller and use it like below,

```
data = $filter('filter')(data, {ack === 'true' && status !== 'CLOSED' && status !== 'ESCALATED'});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ES6 `filter()` method applying following condition `filter(item => (item.ack && !["ESCALTED", "CLOSED"].includes(item.status))`
console.log(filteredData)

```js
const data = [{
    status: "ESCALTED",
    name: "A1",
    ack: true
  },
  {
    status: "ESCALTED",
    name: "A2",
    ack: true
  },
  {
    status: "CLOSED",
    name: "A3",
    ack: true
  },
  {
    status: "NEW",
    name: "A4",
    ack: false
  },
  {
    status: "NEW",
    name: "A5",
    ack: true
  }
];
const filteredData = data.filter(item => (item.ack && !["ESCALTED", "CLOSED"].includes(item.status)));
console.log(filteredData)
```